# Launching jQuery method using Asp.Net control

Tags: jquery, asp.net, verification

I try to launch a jQuery method when I select a file from FileUpload control in Asp.Net but it does not work. The jQuery method has to check the file size that is selected. How can I fix this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ValidateUploadButton() {
        //this code will be executed when a new file is selected
        $('#FileUpload1').bind('change', function () {
            //converts the file size from bytes to MB 
            var fileSize = this.files[0].size / 1024;

            //checks whether the file is less than 1 MB 
            if (fileSize > 1) {
                $('#errorMessage').html("The file is too big")
                alert("okey");
                //successfully validated 
            }
            else {
                alert("else");
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" ClientValidationFunction="ValidateUploadButton" />
<span id="errorMessage"></span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed your ClientValidationFunction attribute to onchange.

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" onchange="ValidateUploadButton();" />
<span id="errorMessage"></span>
```

Edited the script to remove the 'change' bind since now ValidateUploadButton is called because of the change.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ValidateUploadButton()
{
    //this code will be executed when a new file is selected
    //converts the file size from bytes to Ko 
    var fileSize = $('#FileUpload1')[0].files[0].size / 1024 / 1024;
    // USE THIS BELOW IF THE ONE ABOVE DOESN'T WORK
    //var fileSize = $('#<%= FileUpload1.ClientID %>')[0].files[0].size / 1024 / 1024;

    //checks whether the file is less than 1 MB 
    if (fileSize > 1)
    {
        $('#errorMessage').html("The file is too big")
        alert("okey");
        //successfully validated 
    }
    else
    {
        alert("else");
    }
}
</script>
```

**EDIT**

Sorry I failed to test this thoroughly. It should work now. The javascript syntax of properly referencing the filesize was wrong. Also I added an extra division of 1024 so you will get it in MB instead of KB.

Note - This only works on one file, not supported for multiple files.

Comment: @HQtunes.com Yep, I failed to test it before posting. It works for me now so hopefully it works for you. Also note the commented out fileSize var. Because your fileupload is runat=server, sometimes the actual reference ID changes(I believe because of content-masterpage) so you might have to get its ID differently like in the commented out line.